# Find all browsers installed in a machine using active X in IE -Javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I need to search what all browsers are installed in  a system using ActiveX . I am able to open a link from IE to chrome using ActiveX.

Sample Code

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("chrome http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. Without certain extensions, Chrome does not support ActiveX. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I am running a html page in IE, i need to check whether IE is the only browser installed. So for that i need to check what all browsers are installed. Since its IE we can use ActiveX, using shell.run i can run exe files, is there any way to retrieve the Browsers list installed in that machine

Comment: @danish is there any way?

Comment: Do you really have to do it from browser? This won't work in most cases. There are ways to identify installed s/w from ActiveX but I would simply not do it. Why are doing it anyway?

Comment: Yes that's the only way , can you help me on listing the browsers name installed in the machine. It would be a great help

Comment: Given the fact that soon IE will be gone, why spend the time to implement something that won't last?

Comment: need to have a solution on this is there any way